# "Unable to scan program's header" debugging Delphi .dll from .NET app

Tags: .net, delphi

I'm working with a 64 bit .DLL built with Delphi XE3 Version 17.0.4770.56661
This .dll is called from a 64 bit .Net App using .Net framework version 4.6.2  Calling the .dll from the .net app works fine, except when trying to debug.  From within Delphi, I specify the path and name of the .net app and attempt to launch.  When I do, I receive the following error message: "Unable to scan program's header"

Help is appreciated.

Comment: As a work-around you should be able to start the process and then attach to it once it’s running.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Tried that from Delphi but I get 'Unable to create process'

Comment: Tried what - attach? - it should not be creating a process at that point.

Comment: Tried attaching to the .net app from Delphi, with the .dll project open.  I don't know what either error message means.  'Unable to create process' or 'Unable to scan program's header'

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Unfortunately I don't have Delphi installed ATM, so I can't offer more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

check please, that the .Net Application has 64x option (not AnyCPU) setted as a Platform target on Build-Tab in VS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).